# Image retain proportions as it scales down using XD responsive resize

Tags: icon, interface-design, resize, adobe-xd, responsive-design

I'm having this recurring issue with XD where i want to resize a group of elements where one element is an image, without changing the proportions of the image which needs to remain 16:9. In this particular example i want an icon to stay in the lower right hand corner of the image, with 16px spacing against the edges of the image. The image itself sits inside a rectangular background element:

[image]

And ideally what i would like to happen is that when i resize it, the image retains its proportions and scales down, but the icon retains its size and it's spacing

[image]

But what happens is that the image does not keep its proportions as it resizes. I've tried 2 approaches both of which fail:

**1. Use image inside a containing shape:** i make a 16:9 rectangle, then i drag the image from my finder window into that rectangle. Essentially making it a background image to that rectangle.

What happens here is that although the icon retains its relative position and shape the image loses its proportions and gets cropped.

[image]

**2. Use image itself:** I just drag the image in to the artboard, and i group that image with the other elements. And what happens here is that the image does retain it's proportions, but the icons floats around as i change the shape according to the position of my cursor.
[image]

Is there an option i have missed here? I have tried a bunch of different manual responsive resize options, but all of the obvious options haven't worked. obviously I need set the icon to fix width and height and then fixed to right and bottom

[image]

But what kind of responsive resize settings do i use for the image that ensures the image retains its proportions whilst scaling down and also keeps the icon in the lower right hand corner? Is this even possible in XD? Have i missed something obvious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution. I had indeed overlooked something simple. I had confused "fix width/heigh" option with the "lock aspect" option.:

[image]

I locked the aspect ratio on the image (i believe it was locked by default), and then put the icon on top of the image at the desired position in the lower right hand corner. I grouped the icon and image together, i then made sure the icon used the manual resize options i mentioned in my question, fixing it to bottom and right. And once i did that all i needed to do was to lock the aspect ratio on the group as well and voila it worked!

Hopefully this answer will be helpful for someone else who is also overlooking this simple solution.

Edit: After the last step of locking the aspect ratio of the group, double check that it hasn't automatically set the groups width to be fixed, i find that happens everytime i do this.